# How to efficiently animate changing mesh on a fixed 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, animation, mesh

Say I'd like to visualise a height function of a torus by animating a plane going upwards, and highlighting the intersection via `Mesh`/`MeshFunctions`. I draw the torus using `ParametricPlot3D`, and I would like it to be very smooth and nice looking, so I put somewhat high values of `PlotPoints` and/or `MaxRecursion`. I produce an animation using `Table` with the parameter being the value in `Mesh`.

Now the problem is, that each frame of my animation recomputes the torus, which takes a lot of time. Is there a way to only compute the torus once, and then just compute different meshes for each frame? Maybe I could compute all the meshes while computing the plot, and then just display one at the time? Can I extract meshes as, say, `GraphicsComplex` and combine it back with the plot in `Show`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far. Your question is less likely to get answered if people have to spend a bunch of time just trying to figure out how to recreate the animation from your description alone. If people can just take your code and run it to see how it works, they're much more likely to be able to offer a solution if one exists.

Comment: @MassDefect Right, I'll keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible with some amount of effort. The key is to make separate plots of the surface without the meshlines, and a plot with just the meshlines. Since the OP did not bother to put in example code, I wrote up the following:

```
p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[u]) Cos[v], (3 + Cos[u]) Sin[v], Sin[u]},
                      {u, -π, π}, {v, -π, π}, Lighting -> "Classic", Mesh -> None, 
                      PlotPoints -> 95, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 1]]

Animate[Show[p1,
             ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[u]) Cos[v], (3 + Cos[u]) Sin[v], Sin[u]},
                              {u, -π, π}, {v, -π, π}, Mesh -> {{h}},
                              MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},  
                              MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5],
                                                     ColorData[97, 4]], 
                              PlotPoints -> 45, PlotStyle -> None]],
        {h, -1, 1, 1/10}]
```

I have deliberately omitted showing the output, so that you can evaluate and see for yourself what happens with this code.

Comment: Your last bit to this answer somehow reminds me of, “...left up to the reader.”, except that I would much rather have what you wrote, haha! How robust/smooth is `Show` when wrapped with something like `Animate` or `Manipulate`? Awesome answer as always, J.M.—I look forward to evaluating this myself later today :D

Comment: `Show[]`'s only job is to appropriately combine any `Graphics[]`/`Graphics3D[]` object fed to it, and set options for the final display if supplied. So, the quality of the final result is really dependent on the graphics objects fed to it.

Comment: Ah! Many thanks. I was mostly curious about things such as jittery animations & the-like, so that bodes well! Good deal.

Comment: +1 The animation is smoother with finer steps, e.g., `{h, -1, 1, 1/100}` and adding the option `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}]` to the `Show` makes the `Mesh` travel clearer.

Comment: Aha! That is simpler than I thought. So setting `PlotStyle->None` makes it compute just the `Mesh`, and I can still control how smooth the `Mesh` itself will be with `PlotPoints`. So not only does it speed up the process, I can also potentially make the Mesh more/less detailed than the rest of the plot. Sorry for not including an example, I'll keep that in mind next time (now you already wrote the important part of what I had). Thank you for a great quick answer! (for my working example ~60s-->~2s, and since two seconds are mostly the plot itself, it's really like \inf-->2s, hehe) Thanks!